# C - Socket Chat Server with thread - Nickname array

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets

I'm doing a chat server using sockets and thread in C, but I have different problem :
- I'm not able to send a message to client using his nickname
- I've got a problem sending a message and attach the client sender nickname
Can you help me on this please ?

How I fix the nickname :

```
          /* Asks for client nickname */
          if (strcmp(clients_nick[client], "") == 0) {
            write(fd, msg, strlen(msg) * sizeof(char));
            int rc = read(fd, buf, BUFLEN);

            if (rc > 0) {
              /* Deleting the character \n */
              buf[strlen(buf) - 1] = '\0';
              snprintf(clients_nick[client], MAX_NICK_LENGTH - 1, "%s", buf);
            }

          }
```

How I send the message :
        void
        client_write_message (
            char * msg,
            int    client_sender,
            int    client_receiver) 
        {
          char * buffer;
          buffer = calloc(BUFLEN, sizeof(char));

```
      snprintf(buffer, BUFLEN, "[%s", clients_nick[client_sender]);
      buffer[strlen(clients_nick[client_sender])] = ']';
      snprintf(buffer, BUFLEN, " %s", msg);

      write(clients[client_receiver], msg, strlen(msg) * sizeof(char));

      buffer[0] = '\0';

      free(buffer);
    }
```

Comment: Don't post hundreds of lines of code and the ask a general question about it, where we have to search in your code.  Do post the shortest piece of code that shows the problem, and ask a specific question, pointing it out in the code where possible.

Answer (score 2):

This is incorrect:

```
buf[strlen(buf) - 1] = '\0';
```

as [`read()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) does not append a null terminator, upon which `strlen()` depends. The value returned by `strlen()` is unknown and may result in accessing out of bounds on `buf`. Remove the null terminator assignment and replace with:

```
if (rc > 0)
{
    snprintf(clients_nick[client], MAX_NICK_LENGTH - 1, "%.*s", rc, buf);
}
```

The result of `read()` is the number of characters read, stored in `rc` in the posted code, and the format specifier `%.*s` uses a length and buffer and does not require the buffer to be null terminated.

Comment: Okay, but I don't want the '\n' at the end. It works with it too ?

Comment: @user2269756, then use `rc - 1` instead if the newline character is present.